# Change levels and labels using the `as_factor` R haven function for table1 output

Tags: r, r-factor, r-haven

I am trying to create a descriptive statistics table using the [table1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/table1/vignettes/table1-examples.html#a-column-of-p-values) with p-values and data from an SAV file. I read in the file using `read_sav` from the `haven` package.

```
library(haven)
library(table1)
library(tidyverse)

df<- read_sav(filename)

outcome_var = 'treatment'
test_df <- tibble(treatment = c(1,0,0,0,1,0), x = 1:6, y = rnorm(6))
```

which reads in the data as a `tibble`. To create the table1, the `treatment` variable must be a factor type. Normally, I'd change the column using the link above like

```
library(MatchIt)
data(lalonde)

lalonde$treat    <- factor(lalonde$treat, levels=c(0, 1, 2), labels=c("Control", "Treatment", "P-value"))
```

However, when I do

`factor(test_df[,outcome_var], levels=c(0, 1, 2), labels=c("Not Treated", "Treated", "P-value")`

the `treatment` column is returned as NULL. If I use the `as_factor` function from `haven`, I can't pass levels or labels.

I expect an output like the table shown in the table1 link above.

How can I change the levels and labels using `as_factor` to include the p-values column? Or is there a way to use `factor` without it returning NULL to the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the `tibble` data frame to a normal data frame, then you can use `factor` and your p-value script to produce your Table 1.

```
test_df <- as.data.frame(test_df)

test_df$treatment <- factor(test_df$treatment, levels=c(0, 1, 2), labels=c("Not Treated", "Treated", "P-value"))

table1(~ x + y | treatment, data = test_df, render = rndr)
```

Note that I used `test_df$treatment` instead of `test_df[, outcome]`. Each method returns a different structure and `factor` uses the one that `test_df$treatment` returns.